# Loop Through Subfolders And Combine Text files Within - Output Combined File To a Folder

Tags: file, loops, powershell, text

I have a directory of subfolders. Each one contains text files within it. I am trying to combine the files found in each subfolder.

**Example:**

SubFolder 1 → **a.txt + b.txt + c.txt** → SubFolder1Merged.txt
SubFolder 2 → **x.txt + y.txt + z.txt** → SubFolder2Merged.txt

I have referenced [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12374140/combine-content-of-several-files-in-folder).

This is what I have so far:

```
$startingDir = "C:\Users\WP\Desktop\TextFiles"

function CombineLogs {
  param([string]$startingDir)

  dir $startingDir -Filter *.txt | Get-Content |
    Out-File (Join-Path $startingDir COMBINED.txt)  

  dir $startingDir | ?{ $_.PsIsContainer } | %{ CombineLogs $_.FullName }
}

CombineLogs 'C:\Users\WP\Desktop\CombinedTextFiles'  #output the combined text files here
```

I get a `combined.txt` generated in CombinedTextFiles - but not individual files merged.
Also the file is empty.

I simply want to loop through each subfolder, merge the text files within each folder, then output to my CombinedTextfiles Folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function CombineLogs
{
  param([string] $startingDir)

  $outputFile = (Split-Path $startingDir -Leaf) + "COMBINED.txt"

  dir $startingDir -Filter *.txt |
      Get-Content | 
         Out-File (Join-Path $outputDir $outputFile)  

  dir $startingDir |?{ $_.PsIsContainer } | %{ CombineLogs $_.FullName }
}

$outputDir ='C:\Users\WP\Desktop\CombinedTextFiles' # output the combined text files here
CombineLogs "C:\Users\WP\Desktop\TextFiles"
```

Above code snippet would solve `TextFilesCOMBINED.txt` and `NewCOMBINED.txt` however does not solve `ABCCOMBINED.txt` nor `xyzCOMBINED.txt` in next scenario:

```
C:\Users\WP\Desktop\TextFiles\ABC\ABC
C:\Users\WP\Desktop\TextFiles\ABC\xyz\ABC
C:\Users\WP\Desktop\TextFiles\New
C:\Users\WP\Desktop\TextFiles\xyz\ABC
```

Comment: Hi JosefZ, this is smashing! :) - it combined the text files brilliantly. I will only have 1 level folder down to keep things simple. If I may ask for a huge favor of your expertise  - if I wanted to combine docx files  - is that more advanced  - how would I go about that? Thank you so much

Comment: Google for something like `powershell merge docx files`. It extends original topic much too. @wp44 if my answer was helpful, please consider marking it as accepted. [See this page](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/) for an explanation of why this is important.

Answer (score 1):

Recursion can be tricky if you don't know how to handle it. And in this case you don't need to implement recursion yourself anyway. Just let PowerShell do the heavy lifting for you:

```
$startingDir = 'C:\Users\WP\Desktop\TextFiles'
$combinedDir = 'C:\Users\WP\Desktop\CombinedTextFiles'

Get-ChildItem $startingDir -Recurse | Where-Object {
  $txtfiles = Join-Path $_.FullName '*.txt'
  $_.PSIsContainer -and (Test-Path $txtfiles)
} | ForEach-Object {
  $merged = Join-Path $combinedDir ($_.Name + '_Merged.txt')
  Get-Content $txtfiles | Set-Content $merged
}
```

Comment: Thank you Ansgar - This is Brilliant :)  I was not expecting another answer. In future - I will wait - thank you to both Gentlemen who helped solve this.