# Powershell Recursion Loop through SubFolders - and Combine Binary Docx Files

Tags: file, powershell, merge, binary

Yesterday, I received brilliant help for combining text files in Sub folders.

I wanted to extend that to help me merge binary .docx files.

**Example:**

SubFolder 1 → **a.docx+ b.docx+ c.docx** →    SubFolder1Merged.docx

SubFolder 2 →  **p.docx + q.docx + z.docx + f.docx** → SubFolder2Merged.docx

etc...

I have referenced Ansgars Answer to help me.

[Loop Through Subfolders And Combine Text files Within - Output Combined File To a Folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36208116/loop-through-subfolders-and-combine-text-files-within-output-combined-file-to)

```
$startingDir = 'C:\Users\WP\Desktop\DocxFiles'
$combinedDir = 'C:\Users\WP\Desktop\CombinedDocxFiles'


$Word = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application
$objWord.Visible = $False

Foreach ($File in $Files) {
 $Doc = $Word.Documents.Open($File.FullName)

Get-ChildItem $startingDir -Recurse | Where-Object {
$docxFiles = Join-Path $_.FullName '*.docx'
$_.PSIsContainer -and (Test-Path $docxFiles)
} | ForEach-Object {
$merged = Join-Path $combinedDir ($_.Name + '_Merged.docx')
Get-Content $docxFiles | Set-Content $merged
}
}
```

No error, however -  no files are out put or combined. I am sure I am missing some .com api? 
I have been researching this since yesterday and have not found anything to help me solve this issue.

My skill set with powershell is very new and I am not conversant in VBscript - if at all that is a different option.

Thank you for any assistance.

Comment: Binary files can't be processed via `Get-Content`, and they can't be merged by simple concatenation like text files. Did you check Google, as JosefZ had suggested? Do you have Word at your disposal?

Comment: Question: is this all of your code? If so, how is `$Files` being initialized? It would just be $null.

Comment: Hi, I have been researching this since yesterday, I have not been able to locate any powershell code  that merges docx files to help me. :(